# Problemas com a função wp_mail( ); do wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Desenvolvi um plugin para Wordpress, já testei na hostgator, funcionou corretamente. Quando coloquei na Digital Ocean, a função `wp_mail();` passa como `true` mas não envia email algum.

Comment: Amigo, você precisa olhar se no seu servidor a função mail do php esta ativo. Muitos servidores de hospedagem não o deixam habilitados devido ao mal uso de alguns usuários. Se estiver desativado, use algum plugin de envio SMTP como o WPSMTP ou Easy SMTP

Comment: Tente isto: [What's the easiest way to setup SMTP settings programmatically?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/75957/12615)

Answer (score 1):

Se não me engano, as instâncias da Digital Ocean não vêm com um servidor SMTP previamente instalado. Você terá que fazer login na instância via SSH e instalar o servidor manualmente, para então utilizá-lo no Wordpress ou em qualquer outra aplicação que você queira.

Esse [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/wordpress-does-not-send-emails) no próprio site da Digital Ocean deve ajudá-lo.

Comment: Obrigado Rodrigo, fiz até uma mascara para encaminhar o email para a caixa do gmail, mas ainda não deu certo.